# i get error in starting virtualbox for genymotion

Tags: runtime-error, virtualbox, genymotion

Get an error on startup genymotion:
" VirtualBox cannot start the virtual device.
To find out the cause of the problem, start the virtual device from VirtualBox.
For more information, chek the log files. "

And when i start API on VirtualBox get error : 
"The virtual machine 'Google Nexus 5 - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 1080x1920' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1). More details may be available in 'C:\Users\Mavara\AppData\Local\Genymobile\Genymotion\deployed\Google Nexus 5 - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 1080x1920\Logs\VBoxHardening.log'.

Result Code: 
E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: 
MachineWrap
Interface: 
IMachine {f30138d4-e5ea-4b3a-8858-a059de4c93fd} "

I opened VirtualBox and selected API and opened setting on top API and uncheck checkbox in audio but the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your virtual machine files is deleted or edited by something like antivirus , viruses or other programs so you can restore files by data recovery softwares or if those files were available in antivirus quarantine restore them